# Npm install discord.js errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to install discord.js but its not working I'm getting these errors:

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\46723\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-04T14_01_04_500Z-debug.log
```

I have tried about 12 solutions but nothing is working.

Comment: And what does  C:\Users\46723\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-04T14_01_04_500Z-debug.log say?

Comment: Have you updated node / npm itself? Which version of npm are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Delete your node modules and restart your pc that fixed it for me